# Suitable question for /tour page with relaxed requirements?

Tags: discussion, tour-page

The [tour page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) (formerly known as “the new /about”) contains a sample question with two answers. This Q&A&A triple has to meet some [stringent requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-about-page/163948#163948); in particular, they have to be short (at most 400 characters) and eschew most formatting. Moderators can choose among eligible questions.

We like posts that are long and detailed, often with bullet points. So unsurprisingly there are no eligible questions, and our tour page contains a demo question about unicorns.

As much as we all love unicorns, having a sample question there is more informative. We [can ask for a dispensation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/relax-the-requirements-for-crazy-formatting-on-the-tour-example-question) from some of the requirements. The box won't grow, however, so if a post is longer, it will be truncated.

Should we stick with a unicorny sample? Or can we find a question with at least two answers which looks decent if only the top 4 lines or so are shown? I'm thinking that posts with a short introductory paragraph followed by bullet points should look decent.

Comment: While I would really like to put a real question in there, I just don't see it happening here. Any question that could possibly fit, even if they shorted the question and lengthened the character limit, would probably be considered a bad question.

Comment: @Seth We can get the requirements relaxed, then the first four lines or so of the posts would appear. You can see the effect in the link to Code Golf.

Comment: I like that idea much better than unicorns - let them play silly games while we sail away